# process.env is returned undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dotenv

i have a .env file in root like:

```
JWT_SECRET=MySecret
```

and I am trying to reach this value like :

```
const jwtSecret: string = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
```

but process.env returned undefined.

I use dotenv on the app.ts like:

```
    const dotenvResult = dotenv.config();
if (dotenvResult.error) {
    throw dotenvResult.error;
}
```

where could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: How did you use `dotenv`?

Comment: As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv. `require('dotenv').config()`  (as per [the docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage))

Comment: If the `.env` file is in a different directory with the `app.ts` file, you will need to provide the `path` in the config method.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh no , both in root directory